# Correctly closing of new ViewController pages

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, presentviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

Help me please with my ViewControllers closing.
Im open new ViewController ("SettingsPage") with this code:

```
settingClass = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SettingsPage") as! SettingsClass
settingClass.modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen
settingClass.modalTransitionStyle = .CrossDissolve
self.presentViewController(settingClass, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then im need to go back (close SettingsPage) and when im used this method ill get doubles of MainView

```
mainClass = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainView") as! ViewController
mainClass.modalTransitionStyle = .CrossDissolve
self.presentViewController(mainClass, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

how to correctly close new ViewController ("SettingsPage") witch open like .OverFullScreen, and go back to my MainView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to close it like this

```
mainClass.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});
```

Comment: Thanks! its work in ViewController witch i want to close I'm use your code
`self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`